# Why fine structure experiments are donewith monochromatic x-ray light?

Tags: spectroscopy, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

What would happen if a broad bandwidth hits a grating and then all the diffraction spectrum goes through the sample and is detected at once?

Comment: So you put the "spectroscopy" tag. And considering that your question mentions "diffraction spectrum", I guess that you are aware of the fact that EXAFS is about measuring a spectrum. In principle you can illuminate the sample with the full spectrum and the put the diffractometer to analyse the transmitted beam (loosing TEY info of course). So your question being what exactly?

Comment: Thanks. My question is which process in the exafs fails if the beam is not monochromatic. Where is the TEY (total electron yield) used, is it in analysis. Arent photons that are collected?

Comment: OK, let me put this into a brief answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out in the question and with the spectroscopy tag, [EXAFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_X-ray_absorption_fine_structure) is a spectroscopy method. In detail on is looking at the binding energies of (core level) electrons. The x-ray absorption strongly increases if the x-ray energy coincides with such an energy (a typical resonance effect, which is additionally applied in [XMCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_magnetic_circular_dichroism)). In principle there are several ways to get a photon spectrum, reflection, absorption, and transmission. As we have x-rays, refection is negligible. Unfortunately, there are no good x-ray mirrors except for grazing incidence.

In any case, the information one wants to get is how much photons are absorbed at a specific energy. This can be done in two ways: 1) Continuously scan the energy of the incoming beam and put a "broad band" analyser, or 2) but a broad band beam ("white light") and analyse the transmitted beam. In either case you need an energy analyser, which is typically a grating.

There are several reason why one starts with a monochromatic beam, i.e. makes an energy scan. One reason e.g. is that the total x-ray "hazard" at the experiment is strongly decreased. In a synchrotron the monochromator is usually in an mostly inaccessible hutch, as here you still have the full dangerous energy range from soft up to very hard x-rays. A second point is that an energy scan gives you additional information about the depth structure of you sample. Upon impact the x-ray produces secondary electrons (assuming conductive bulk material), which can escape the sample. If one checks the current from ground to sample, one also can measure the spectrum. This is the total electron yield (TEY). When the transmission shows a dip, the TEY shows a peak. Most importantly, the two signals have a different depth dependency. The transmission somewhat gives the integrated absorption along the path of the beam. Secondary electrons, however, have a very small escape depth (energy dependent though). This means that if the TEY is very large, the signal is coming from somewhere near the surface, etc. This is especially of interest if one studies multilayer structures of different materials. Also imagine very thick sample with basically zero transmission; in this case you rely on TEY and scanning the energy.

**Update**
The way of getting a spectrum by scanning the energy with a monochromator, as described above, is rather slow. In some cases one might be interested how a spectrum changes, e.g., in a chemical reaction. In this case it is preferred to have "white" light at the point of reaction. One could than diffract the white beam and put "several" detectors in the opening angle. A second approach, from which I know that it is done, is the following: The diffraction is before the sample, but the energy resolved diverging beam is refocused onto the sample, such that at the sample one has white light. After transmission, the different energies diverge again. As the energies have defined angles, an angle resolved intensity measurement can be recalculated in the according spectrum. (E.g. a CCD and one knows which pixel, refers to which angle and, therefore, energy). Note that these are setups for transmission and require samples that are transparent in the energy region of interest.